# Is there a way to write integer to a file in java

Tags: java, export-to-csv, bufferedwriter

I have a program that converts Excel to CSV and I used 2 ways to do this: one of them uses `CsvWriter` write and the other program uses `BufferedWriter` write but the problem that I have encountered here is in order to write an `Integer` to a file you need to convert it to string with

```
String.valueOf(myInt);
```

but I need a pure `Integer` not a string because when I am trying to upload this file in Oracle database it throws me

> Ora-01722 invalid number exception

I tried to create a CSV file from my Windows and Oracle works perfectly fine with that data.

So my question is there a way to write an Integer not a String to a file? Any help?

Comment: Just write the integer to a file. `PrintWriter` has methods that accept integer parameters, so wrap your `BufferedWriter` in one - if you want binary output.

Comment: `I tried to create a Csv file from my windows and oracle works perfectly fine with that data` - so you actually want to create a CSV file? Note that those are _always_ text-based, so if the result doesn't match what you want to get then please provide examples for both the correct format you expect and the wrong format you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataOutputStream` Object to write primitive int value to a file.

**Example:**

```
 //create FileOutputStream object
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);

/*
 * To create DataOutputStream object from FileOutputStream use,
 * DataOutputStream(OutputStream os) constructor.
 */

   DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

   int i = 100;

/*
 * To write an int value to a file, use
 * void writeInt(int i) method of Java DataOutputStream class.
 *
 * This method writes specified int to output stream as 4 bytes value.
 */

   dos.writeInt(i);

/*
 * To close DataOutputStream use,
 * void close() method.
 *
 */

   dos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a DataOutputStream (resp. DataInputStream) to write (resp. read) any primitive Java type to or from a file.